# Can I create a php script to act as FTP

Tags: php, ftp, delete-file

I have a php script I'm using to upload zip files to my ftp and automatically unzip them.

I wonder if there is a finished php script to delete folders and files on my ftp.

Reason I'm asking is because I save so much time doing the zip upload and unzip process instead of unzipping locally and then upload the files.

So now my problem is that it takes quite allot of time to delete folders and files using Filezilla and I want to speed that up.

Anyone with a working solution?

Edit:
Here is my unzip code that I'm using:

```
    <?php
/* Simple script to upload a zip file to the webserver and have it unzipped
  Saves tons of time, think only of uploading Wordpress to the server
  Thanks to c.bavota (www.bavotasan.com)
  I have modified the script a little to make it more convenient
  Modified by: Johan van de Merwe (12.02.2013)
*/

function rmdir_recursive($dir) {
foreach(scandir($dir) as $file) {
if ('.' === $file || '..' === $file) continue;
if (is_dir("$dir/$file")) rmdir_recursive("$dir/$file");
else unlink("$dir/$file");
}

rmdir($dir);
}

if($_FILES["zip_file"]["name"]) {
$filename = $_FILES["zip_file"]["name"];
$source = $_FILES["zip_file"]["tmp_name"];
$type = $_FILES["zip_file"]["type"];

$name = explode(".", $filename);
$accepted_types = array('application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed', 'multipart/x-zip', 'application/x-compressed');
foreach($accepted_types as $mime_type) {
if($mime_type == $type) {
$okay = true;
break;
}
}

$continue = strtolower($name[1]) == 'zip' ? true : false;
if(!$continue) {
$message = "The file you are trying to upload is not a .zip file. Please try again.";
}

/* PHP current path */
$path = dirname(__FILE__).'/'; // absolute path to the directory where zipper.php is in
$filenoext = basename ($filename, '.zip'); // absolute path to the directory where zipper.php is in (lowercase)
$filenoext = basename ($filenoext, '.ZIP'); // absolute path to the directory where zipper.php is in (when uppercase)

$targetdir = $path . $filenoext; // target directory
$targetzip = $path . $filename; // target zip file

/* create directory if not exists', otherwise overwrite */
/* target directory is same as filename without extension */

if (is_dir($targetdir)) rmdir_recursive ( $targetdir);


mkdir($targetdir, 0777);


/* here it is really happening */

if(move_uploaded_file($source, $targetzip)) {
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$x = $zip->open($targetzip); // open the zip file to extract
if ($x === true) {
$zip->extractTo($targetdir); // place in the directory with same name
$zip->close();

unlink($targetzip);
}
$message = "Your .zip file was uploaded and unpacked.";
} else {    
$message = "There was a problem with the upload. Please try again.";
}
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Unzip a zip file to the webserver</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php if($message) echo "<p>$message</p>"; ?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
<label>Choose a zip file to upload: <input type="file" name="zip_file" /></label>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you are connecting to a FTP server and uploading a zip file via PHP Script. If that works for you, why not delete the file on FTP server via PHP also? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-delete.php (don't do it straight away after unzipping, do it on a cron for any uploaded zip file, say older than 1 hour?)

Comment: I just found a script for the unzip. Looking for a finished php script for the delete. I dont know anything about programing...

Comment: Can you post your code, so we can see what you are doing...?

Comment: I have edited my first post with the code. That is the code i am using to unzip a .zip file. That goes really fast comparing to unzip locally and then upload the files/folders. Now i wanted a similar script where i could delete a file/folder on my FTP server. If that is possible, or maybe there are better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to plug my own work here but there is a script I am selling on a website called Code Canyon called MightyFTP that wraps the complex procedural php ftp functionality into a much simpler OO API.

As far as I am aware deleting a folder requires recursive deletion via the current FTP API so there is little bit of work involved normally.

A link to the script is here "http://codecanyon.net/item/mightyftp/8276375"

If you had my code and you wanted to delete an ftp folder the code to do it is very straight forward as demonstrated below.

```
require_once("MightyFTP/FTPClient.php");

$myFtpClient = new MightyFTP\FTPClient("yourftpserver", new MightyFTP\FTPCredentials("yourftpusername", "yourftppassword"));

$ftpDirectoryToDelete = $myFtpClient->getFile("/PathToDirectory/");

$parentDir = $ftpDirectoryToDelete->delete(); //The directory and all its children have been deleted. It will then return the parent of the deleted file/folder.

$ftpDirectoryToDelete->rename(""); //Will throw an exception because you will not be able to run an operation on a file/directory that no longer exists.
```